# How to create a random boolean with chances?

Tags: java, math, libgdx

I saw the libgdx `MathUtils.randomBoolean(chances)`, I guess this would help me but I'm not sure.

```
MathUtils.randomBoolean(10); // I'm not sure if this will give 10% chance?
```

Comment: `Math.random() < .1` should be true in 10% of all invocations. (That's `java.lang.Math`.)

Answer (score 5):

[`MathUtils.randomBoolean(float chance)`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.html#randomBoolean-float-) gives the `true` with probability given by the parameter. But the parameter `chance` can take value between `0 - 1`, meaning that for example `0.1` gives `10%` (`0.1`) probability of returning `true`.

Your example - `10` - would always result in `true` as it's bigger than `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the LibGDX [Javadocs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.html#randomBoolean-float-) regarding `MathUtils`:

> **randomBoolean**
>
> `public static boolean randomBoolean(float chance)`
>
> Returns true if a random value between 0 and 1 is less than the specified value.

That means if you specify a number (passed as an argument), the method will return true if the randomly generated number (between 0 and 1) is less than the passed `chance`. In this case it would be:

```
MathUtils.randomBoolean(0.1);
```

This is because 0.1 is 10%, or 10/100. Thus, a random number between 0 and 1, if less than 0.1, will cause the method to return true.

Your code previously would *always return true* because a number between 0 and 1 is *always* less than 10.